# My connection string is not quite right

Tags: vb.net, connection-string

Hi can someone help me with my connection string, I can navigate around my database but I can not add data to it. Thanks in advance my code is below, if someone an shred some light on it for me that would be great. So I can navigate but I can not add data or update data. I did have this working at one point but have since screed t up. If only I had done a backup of it :(

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
```

Public Class adminPanel

```
Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Dim dbProvider As String
Dim dbSource As String
Dim ds As New DataSet
Dim sql As String
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim inc As Integer
Dim MaxRows As Integer
Private Sub adminPanel(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load


    Dim Builder As New OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With
{
    .ConnectionString = My.Settings.Database1
}
    ' Change it
    Builder.DataSource = IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Database1.mdb")
    lblName.Text = LoginForm.txtUserName.Text
    If lblName.Text = LoginForm.txtUserName.Text Then
        Builder.Add("Jet OLEDB:Database Password", "password")
        Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection With {.ConnectionString = Builder.ConnectionString}
            sql = "SELECT * FROM tblContacts"
            da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
            da.Fill(ds, "Database1")
            'MsgBox("Database is now open")
            MaxRows = ds.Tables("Database1").Rows.Count
            inc = -1

        End Using
    End If

End Sub
Private Sub NavigateRecords()

    UserName.Text = CStr(ds.Tables("Database1").Rows(inc).Item(1))
    UserPassword.Text = CStr(ds.Tables("Database1").Rows(inc).Item(2))
    UserTimer.Text = ds.Tables("Database1").Rows(inc).Item(3).ToString
End Sub

Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click

    UserName.Text = CStr(ds.Tables("Database1").Rows(inc).Item(1))
    UserPassword.Text = CStr(ds.Tables("Database1").Rows(inc).Item(2))
    UserTimer.Text = CStr(ds.Tables("Database1").Rows(inc).Item(3))
    da.Update(ds, "Database1")
    MsgBox("Data updated")
End Sub


Private Sub btnNext_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNext.Click
    If inc <> MaxRows - 1 Then

        inc = inc + 1

        NavigateRecords()

    Else

        MsgBox("No More Rows")

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnPrevious_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrevious.Click
    If inc > 0 Then

        inc = inc - 1

        NavigateRecords()

    Else

        MsgBox("First Record")

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnLast_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnLast.Click
    If inc <> MaxRows - 1 Then

        inc = MaxRows - 1

        NavigateRecords()

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnFirst_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFirst.Click
    If inc <> 0 Then

        inc = 0

        NavigateRecords()

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub adminPanel_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub


Private Sub btnClear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClear.Click
    MsgBox("Data cleared")
    btnCommit.Enabled = False
    btnAddNew.Enabled = True
    btnUpdate.Enabled = True
    btnDelete.Enabled = True

    inc = 0
    NavigateRecords()
End Sub


Private Sub btnAddNew_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddNew.Click
    btnCommit.Enabled = True
    btnUpdate.Enabled = False
    btnDelete.Enabled = False
    btnAddNew.Enabled = False
    UserName.Clear()
    UserPassword.Clear()
    UserTimer.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub btnCommit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCommit.Click
    If inc <> -1 Then

        Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        Dim dsNewRow As DataRow
        dsNewRow = ds.Tables("Database1").NewRow()
        dsNewRow.Item("UserName") = UserName.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("UserPassword") = UserPassword.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("UserTimer") = UserTimer.Text
        ds.Tables("Database1").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)
        da.Update(ds, "Database1")
        MsgBox("New Record added to the Database")
        btnCommit.Enabled = False
        btnAddNew.Enabled = True
        btnUpdate.Enabled = True >
        btnDelete.Enabled = True

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    If MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to Delete this Record?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) = DialogResult.No Then

        MsgBox("Operation Cancelled")
        Exit Sub

    End If
    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

    ds.Tables("Database1").Rows(inc).Delete()
    MaxRows = MaxRows - 1

    inc = 0
    da.Update(ds, "Database1")
    NavigateRecords()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Forgive my ignorance of `Microsoft Access`, but does it not have the same permissions concept that `SQL Server` does? If so, then have you verified the permissions of the user you are connecting to the database as?

Comment: Hi Karl, I do not have a problem with permissions (I don't think) as I can connect to the database. I know I am connected because I can scroll through the users that are listed in it using the navigation buttons. Ie btnNext, btnPrevious, btnLast, btnFirst all work. I just can not add users or update users information.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with your connection string, unless you're opening the connection as read-only. Also, please [edit] to remove all of the code that is not relevant to your question (like all of the empty methods). It's not helpful to add all of the extra clutter to your code; it makes it more difficult to read and help you solve your problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with your connection string. The code in `btnUpdate_Click` is not updating the database, it is updating the textboxes.

**edit**

btnUpdate_Click should read something like (untested code)

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    ds.Tables("Database1").Rows(inc).Item("UserName") = UserName.Text
    ds.Tables("Database1").Rows(inc).Item("Password") = UserPassword.Text
    ds.Tables("Database1").Rows(inc).Item("UserTimer") = UserTimer.Text
    da.Update(ds, "Database1")
    MsgBox("Data updated")
End Sub
```